# Flag and close vote description still mentions "FAQ" instead of "help center"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, help-center, site-faq

I may be nit-picking right now, but the description for close and flag reasons still say "see the FAQ" instead of "see the help center". This is network-wide.

Can we please fix this?